# C# AutomationElement - Get All Tray Icons Including Hidden (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, windows, automation

I'm using the following code to attempt to get all Tray Icons, including the ones hidden by Windows 10.

```
    public static List<AutomationElement> EnumNotificationIcons()
    {
        var data = new List<AutomationElement>();

        foreach (var button in AutomationElement.RootElement.Find(
                        "User Promoted Notification Area").EnumChildButtons())
        {
            data.Add(button);
        }

        foreach (var button in AutomationElement.RootElement.Find(
                      "System Promoted Notification Area").EnumChildButtons())
        {
            data.Add(button);
        }

        var chevron = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find("Notification Chevron");
        if (chevron != null && chevron.InvokeButton())
        {
            foreach (var button in AutomationElement.RootElement.Find(
                               "Overflow Notification Area").EnumChildButtons())
            {
                data.Add(button);
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

However the list returned only includes **visible** icons. Anything hidden is skipped over. The tray icons hidden aren't being returned.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I've updated the code to look like this. Still not pulling in hidden icons.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141013-00/?p=43863

```
    public static IEnumerable<AutomationElement> EnumNotificationIcons()
    {
        var userArea = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find("User Promoted Notification Area");
        if (userArea != null)
        {
            foreach (var button in userArea.EnumChildButtons())
            {
                yield return button;
            }

            foreach (var button in userArea.GetTopLevelElement().Find("System Promoted Notification Area").EnumChildButtons())
            {
                yield return button;
            }
        }

        var chevron = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find("Notification Chevron");
        if (chevron != null && chevron.InvokeButton())
        {
            foreach (var button in AutomationElement.RootElement.Find("Overflow Notification Area").EnumChildButtons())
            {
                yield return button;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hidden items are not present in the notification area, by definition.

Comment: Ok. So how do I access them?

Comment: If they are hidden, then they aren't there. You can't access something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmmm So there is no way to get at them? I need to automate clicking a win forms app that auto loads as minimized. This is for automated testing

Comment: Them make it visible first. UI automation is for automating UI. So make it part of the UI.

Comment: I can’t make it visible. By definition the app itself on load minimizes to tray. How would I make it visible

Comment: You can automate going to the settings and making it visible. Do what an end user would do.

Comment: What settings? I don’t have a context of the app when I load it up. I’m using a UI test suite test stack white

Comment: What would the user do to click on the icon? That's what you need to automate.

Comment: That’s what I’ve been saying. In order to open the app they have to click the tray icon which on load gets hidden. There is no other way....

Comment: If there's no way for the end user to do something, then there's no way to automate it. Automation is for programmatically automating end user actions.

Comment: This makes no sense. There is a way. The user clicks the little show more tray icon button. It shows them. The user clicks the app...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "There is no other way." Automate what the user would do. Click the "show more" button. Then click the app.

Comment: That’s what I’ve been trying to do with my code originally. The bottom tray only shows a couple icons. How do I automate showing the show more icon then clicking

Comment: I’m following the guide you wrote lol https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141013-00/?p=43863

Comment: The last loop for overflow never has any elements in it

Comment: Do you start over after opening the flyout?

Comment: Hmm not sure I’m using the exact code I posted above. Can you elaborate? Appreciate the help btw!

Comment: You are trying to enumerate the overflow immediately after clicking the button, without even waiting for the overflow to open.

Comment: Is there an async await way to accomplish this?

Comment: please see my update. i'm using your code exactly and it's only pulling visible icons. in my case.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a smililar problem with the same code, but I don't get any output at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following code. I had to force wait it appears.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enums the notification icons in the Tray.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List of Notification Icons from the Tray.</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<AutomationElement> EnumNotificationIcons()
    {
        var userArea = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find(UINotificationAreaConstants.UserPromotedNotificationArea);
        if (userArea != null)
        {
            foreach (var button in userArea.EnumChildButtons())
            {
                yield return button;
            }

            foreach (var button in userArea.GetTopLevelElement().Find(UINotificationAreaConstants.SystemPromotedNotificationArea).EnumChildButtons())
            {
                yield return button;
            }
        }

        var chevron = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find(UINotificationAreaConstants.NotificationChevron);
        if (chevron != null && chevron.InvokeButton())
        {
            var elm = AutomationElement.RootElement.Find(
                                UINotificationAreaConstants.OverflowNotificationArea);

            WaitForElm(elm);

            foreach (var button in elm.EnumChildButtons())
            {
                yield return button;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Waits for elm to be ready for processing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="targetControl">The target control.</param>
    /// <returns>The WindowPattern.</returns>
    private static WindowPattern WaitForElm(AutomationElement targetControl)
    {
        WindowPattern windowPattern = null;

        try
        {
            windowPattern =
                targetControl.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern)
                as WindowPattern;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // object doesn't support the WindowPattern control pattern
            return null;
        }
        // Make sure the element is usable.
        if (!windowPattern.WaitForInputIdle(10000))
        {
            // Object not responding in a timely manner
            return null;
        }
        return windowPattern;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution,
I am using WinForms targeting .Net 7, I cannot resolve the missing namespaces required for this code to run. What am I missing? could you please share the required namespaces and/or nuget packages?
Thanks very much.